# Call method or class aar in Flutter Project?

Tags: java, flutter, sdk, aar

I have integrated an AAR into my Flutter project. How can I call a method or class from the AAR in Flutter code? When I try to call it in this file, it says it cannot be imported. The documentation states that the class name is my.com.xxx.xxx. How do I call it? Your assistance is appreciated as this is my first time. Thank you.
[here my java class in flutter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/14hce.png)